# JAXB delegating xml description to inner field, and marshalling of joda LocalDateTime

Tags: jaxb, jodatime

There is some class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType
public class DateAndTime {
    private org.joda.time.LocalDateTime time
}
```

In another class there is some field:

```
@XmlElement
private DateAndTime begin;
```

How should I annotate `DateAndTime` class and `time` field, to make `begin` field in resulting xml look like this: `<begin>01.10.2011 15:20:17</begin>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `time` field/property with `@XmlValue` to get the behaviour you are looking for.

**Note**

I have written about using JAXB with Joda-Time on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: I'v got some error: `@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class. this problem is related to the following location: at protected org.joda.time.LocalDateTime org.example.DateAndTime.value <…>`. What does this error could mean?

Comment: Does your `DateAndTime` class extend from something?

Comment: Yes: `import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.*; public abstract class ToStringSupertype { public String toString() { return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE); } }`

Comment: @Errandir - Can you add `@XmlTransient` to that class?